# Put string into Integer

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm very new to the C# Language. How can I put string into a int?

I've tried the following:

```
number gets filled from database value and I can't change the database field type....

int getal = number; //where number is a String.
```

Comment: while it is a question with an answer... surely you could use google/text books to answer such a basic question. With all due respect this is 101 stuff. You won't get far in Software without knowing how to use the resources available to you.

Comment: @daveL Since he is new to C#, still doesn't make him a search expert like you, you can't know if hes totally new to using a computer etc...

Comment: @RaZor with all due respect again; a search expert one does not need to be (whatever a search expert is)

Comment: @RaZor: However, if you use `Put string into Integer c#`(so his title) in a search engine you'll get good results.

Comment: @daveL Well i agree with your views but then i think may be he did his minimum searching but on this platform rather than google , Somehow let's welcome this chap with this http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As per "How do I ask a good question?" instructions this is a good question. The SO results for "Put string into Integer" that are in C# are not that good so asking the question was justified.

Comment: @rushonerok Guess he rushed through the "How do I ask a good question?" and just asked the question! Well Let's give him the advice to Read the Manual before posting such question!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this:

```
//With this 'number' will converted to an Integer 
int getal = Convert.ToInt32(number);
```

or you can try this:

```
int getal;
if(int.TryParse(number, out getal))
{
    // the number is valid, parse was succesfull!
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RaZor, you were the first that answered my question! Thanks alot! It works thank you thank you thank you!!

Comment: You're welcome! And welcome to the awesome C# Developing language!

Answer (score 4):

Use [`int.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
int getal = int.Parse(number); // can throw an exception if the format is invalid
```

or to validate the number:

```
int getal;
if(int.TryParse(number, out getal))
{
    // valid int, the value is now parsed successfully
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `int.Parse`

```
int getal = int.Parse(number);
```

You can also use `int.TryParse` so that in case of an exception, It won't stop your program. Rather it will just output `0`

```
int getal;
bool valid = int.TryParse(number, out getal); //in this case *getal* is the converted string
```

You can also use the *valid* variable to check whether it is a valid int.

Comment: *getal* needs to stay an Integer...

Comment: @Fnat1c Yes it is an integer. To confirm use `Console.WriteLine(getal.GetType());`. It will output `System.Int32`

Answer (score 1):

As this integer is coming from a database a nullable integer would be a better type to use

```
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(number)){
   return new int?;
} else {
 // use try parse
```

Answer (score 0):

More safe way would be to use int.TryParse:

```
//
// See if we can parse the 'text' string. If we can't, TryParse
// will return false. Note the "out" keyword in TryParse.
//
string text1 = "x";
int num1;
bool res = int.TryParse(text1, out num1);
if (res == false)
{
    // String is not a number.
}

//
// Use int.TryParse on a valid numeric string.
//
string text2 = "10000";
int num2;
if (int.TryParse(text2, out num2))
{
    // It was assigned.
}

//
// Display both results.
//
Console.WriteLine(num1);
Console.WriteLine(num2);
```